# ROS/ROS2 on buildroot

Tags: ros, odroid

I would like to run ROS or ROS2 on an Odroid C4 board with a Buildroot base OS (kernel 6.4). I know that it is possible to run it with Yocto but I have not seen any Buildroot packages.

I cannot switch back to an other OS than the one build by Buildroot.
Has anyone already tried to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [implementation for ROS 1](https://github.com/mchalain/br_ros) from 2019 and another one [for the NanoPi Neo4](https://github.com/flatmax/buildroot.rk3399.external/tree/master/package/rockchip/ros).

For ROS 2 they seem to struggle, see [this mailing list thread](https://lore.kernel.org/all/74102482-7c2d-b08b-f97e-80cc54f03722@mind.be/T/).